# Dealing with non-trivial command and event payloads in Axon

Tags: java, spring, axon

Whenever I take a look at [Axon Bank](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonBank) I start wondering whether I should follow a set of design rules for events and commands.

In Axon Bank both events and commands exclusively consist of primitives. In my applications I tend to avoid primitive usage as much as possible, mainly to build an expressive domain and to have type safety wherever I can get it.

Axon itself comes around with some DDD references but no matter which documents I browse, not a single example makes use of compound objects as part of event/command payloads.

Which confuses me. There is built-in-support for full-blown xml and json serialization capable of more than just having some key-value pairs.

I understand that especially events tend to be small and simple structures since they only reflect incremental state changes but there will always be some kind of gap between a complex domain model and an event (entry).

---

In my domain I could have a bunch of Classes like `OverdraftLimit`, `CurrentBalance`, `Deposit` and `AccountIdentifier`.

Now there are two possible ways to design events and commands:

### 1. Primitives and extensive converting

- Treat Events as raw data with a nice label on it
- Convert raw data to powerful objects as soon as it "enters" the application
- When creating events simply strip them down again.

  ```
  public class BankAccountcreatedEvent {
      private final String accountIdentifier;
      private final int overdraftLimt;

      // ...
  }
  ```

  And somewhere else:

  ```
  public void on (BankAccountCreatedEvent event) {
      this.accountIdentifier = AccountIentifier.fromString(event.getAccountIdentifier());
      this.overdraftLimit = new OverdraftLimit(event.getOverdraftLimit());
  }
  ```

**Pros:**

- Simple command/event API that does not have any weird dependencies
- Makes distribution easier
- Upcasters will only be needed if the actual event structure changes and therefore can be anticipated easily.

**Cons:**

- A huge conversion layer needs to be written and maintained
- Decoupling events/commands and the rest of the domain model for mainly technical reasons introduces a new, artificial, contextual gap

### 2. Expressive Payloads

- Use sophisticated types directly as attributes

  ```
  public class BankAccountCreatedEvent {
      private final BankAccountIdentifier bankAccountIdentifier;
      private final OverdraftLimit overdraftLimit;

      //..
  }
  ```

**Pros:**

- Less to write, easier to read
- Keep together what naturally belongs together

**Cons:**

- Domain logic influences event structure indirectly, upcasting will be needed more frequently and will be less predictable.

I need a second opinion. Is there a recommended way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary thing to keep in mind is that the serialized form of the Event is your formal contract. How you represent that in Java classes is up to each application, in the end. If you configure your serializer to ignore unknown fields, you can leave fields you don't care about out, for example.

Personally, I don't mind primitives in Events. However, I do understand the value of using explicit Value Objects for certain fields, as they allow you to express the "mathematics" involved with each of them. In the case of identifiers, they prevent a "mix-up" where an identifier is used to accidentally attempt to identify another type of object.

In the end, it doesn't matter that much. With a few simple Jackson annotations, you can translate these Value Objects to a simple value in JSON. Check out [@JsonValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html), for example.

```
public class BankAccountCreatedEvent {
    private final BankAccountIdentifier bankAccountIdentifier;
    private final OverdraftLimit overdraftLimit;

    //..
}
```

would map to:

```
{
    "bankAccountIdentifier": "abcdef1234",
    "overdraftLimit" : 1000
}
```

If the BankAccountIdentifier and OverdraftLimit classes would both have an @JsonValue annotated method that would return their 'simple' value.